# Improve calculation efficiency in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, processing-efficiency

I have over 300k records (rows) in my dataset and I have a tab that stratifies these records into different categories and does conditional calculations. The issue with this is that it takes approximately an hour to run this tab. Is there any way that I can improve calculation efficiency in tableau?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: If you want to improve performance you should try to profile your code and see where the hot spots are. Your question in the current form is probably not specific enough so that anyone can answer you.

Comment: Hi, You can try doing all you calculations part in SQL (assuming that is your data source) and take only the processed values to tableau. This will increase the performance. For example: If you have a select query in the tableau data source the Tableau Engine will apply some aggregations over your query in order to get the data as per your table calculations. This can slower your performance. In my case it was and  i did all the calculations in my SQL end and took only the calculated values to tableau and it was working fast.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the issue is accessing your source data. I have found this problem working directly live data as an sql dabase.

An easy solution is to **use extracts**. Quoting [Tableau Improving Database Query Performance article](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/database-query-performance)

> Extracts allow you to read the full set of data pointed to by your data connection and store it into an optimized file structure specifically designed for the type of analytic queries that Tableau creates. These extract files can include performance-oriented features such as pre-aggregated data for hierarchies and pre-calculated calculated fields (reducing the amount of work required to render and display the visualization).

**Edited**

If you are using an extraction and you still have performance issues I suggest to you to massage your source data to be more friendly for tableau, for example, generate pre-calculated fields on [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) process.

Comment: I was using extract as data source. I will read into the article. Thanks!

Comment: You mean than using a full extract you have performance problems? I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: I'd also recommend offloading your conditional calcs to the datasource layer, reducing the computational load on Tableau desktop.

Comment: You can optimize your extract to pre-compute and materialize some row level calculated fields. Under the extract menu. You can also hide unused fields before building your extract, and filter out unused rows. The last two steps reduce the size of the extract.

Comment: @John What are your calculations. If you can post then we can think if optimising that. Also, depends upon how many marks you are plotting in your viz . There are a lot of factor involved here . Unless you share your work here we can only guess.